# Project structure in Julia with clean separation

Tags: julia

I am trying to correctly configure julia project.
The project had initially:

- One module in its own directory
- Another "kind of module" in another directory, but there was no module keyword and it was patched together with help of includes.
- A few files in the root to execute it all by just running "julia run.jl" for example.
- No packages, no `Project.toml` no `Manifest.toml` - there is "packages.jl", which manually calls "Pkg.add" to for preset list of dependencies.
- Not all includes were used to put it all together, there was some fiddling with `LOAD_PATH`

Logically the project contains 3 parts that I see there and something as I would see as "packages" in for example python world.

- One "Common" module with basic util functions shared by all interested modules.
- One module A, which has dependency on "Common".
- Module B, which has dependency on A and "Common".

What I did is, I created 3 modules in their separate directories and to put it all together. These modules make sense internally and there is no real reason to expose them "outside". The whole code is in the end executable and there would be exposed probably just one function, that executes everything. I created loader file, which included all 3 module files. That way I got rid of `LOAD_PATH` and references in IDE started to work. This works for our purposes, but still isn't ideal. I have been reading quite a lot about Julia structure and possibilities - modules, packages, but still don't understand fully. And `Revise` doesn't work.

Is it correct to have modules like this? I like modules as they clearly set boundaries between modules using export lines.
I would also like to make the code as compatible with IDE as possible (LOAD_PATH settings didn't work for VS code and references to functions were broken) and also with `Revise`.

- What is the typical structure for this?
- How to clearly separate code while make the development easy?
- How to make this work with `Revise`?
- I expect it's good idea to make a package for this, but should I make it for the whole project? Then it would mean one "project" module and 3 submodules A, B and Common?
- Or should it be 3(4) packages per module?

Thanks for any output. Comparison of some of the principles to Python/Java/kotlin/C#/Javascript module/packages could be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at DrWatson it provieds some conventions for project management in julia https://juliadynamics.github.io/DrWatson.jl/dev/project/ , see the src vs scripts part, it helped me to decide whats a module and what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [CubicEoS.jl](https://github.com/vvpisarev/CubicEoS.jl) I've made a *single* package which provides *two modules*: `CubicEoS` with general algorithms and `CubicEoS.BrusilovskyEoS` with an implementation of necessary interface to make CubicEoS works on a concrete case. The last module depends on the first. Revise works well. As a *user* (not developer) of CubicEoS, I have scripts which run some calculations.

So, in your case, I would create a single package with four modules. The forth module is a hood for the others: Common, A and B. The possible file structure maybe like this

```
src/
  TheHood.jl
  Common/Common.jl
  Module_A/Module_A.jl
  Module_B/Module_B.jl
test/
  ...
examples/  # those may put out of here, but the important examples may be in test/
  ...
Project.toml
```

And, the possible module structure may be like this

```
# TheHood.jl
module TheHood
  export bar

  include("Common/Common.jl")
  include("Module_A/Module_A.jl")
  include("Module_B/Module_B.jl")
end

# Common/Common.jl
module Common
   export util_1, util_2

   using LinearAlgebra

   util_1(x) = "util_1's implementation"
   util_2(x) = "util_2's implementation"
end

# Module_A/Module_A.jl
module Module_A
   import ..Common
   
   export foo

   foo(x) = "foo's implementation"
end

# Module_B/Module_B.jl
module Module_B
   import ..Common
   import ..Module_A
   
   export bar

   bar(x) = "bar's implementation"
end
```

Now, I'll answer the questions

> What is the typical structure for this?

If the modules does not use independently, I would use the structure above. For small projects I've found "one package = one module" strategy painful when a core package updates.

> How to clearly separate code while make the development easy?

In Julia, a module effectively is a namespace. In inner modules (like A, B, Common), I usually *import* the dev-modules, but *use* modules which a dev-module depends on (see above `using LinearAlgebra` vs `import ..Common`. That's my preference to clarify names.

> How to make this work with Revise?

Turn the code into a package. That's preferable, because `Revise`ing of standlone modules is buggy (at least, in my experience). I'm usually using `Revise` like this

```
% cd where_the_package_lives  # actually, where the project.toml is
% julia --project=.  # or julia and pkg> activate .
% julia> using Revise
% julia> using ThePackage
```

After that I usually can edit source code and call the updated methods w/o restarting of the REPL. But, `Revise` has some limitations.

> I expect it's good idea to make a package for this, but should I make it for the whole project? Then it would mean one "project" module and 3 submodules A, B and Common?

> Or should it be 3(4) packages per module?

You should separate "scripty" (throughaway or command line scripts) and core (reusable) code. The core I would put in a single package. The scripty files (like `examples/`, CLI programs) should be alone `using` the package. The scripty files may define modules or whatever, but their users are endusers, not developers (e.g. running a script involves an i/o operation).

Comment: Thanks, I am exploring this and Watson to see how these things are.

Comment: I am using something similar me too but I would say that if there are no risk of name conflicts between different code parts of your package, using a single module with the various including at the root is a much simpler and effective way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to end this.
The main thing I was missing and would save me a lot of time if I knew:

**If you have your own package, it means the file src/YourPackage.jl will be "imported/included" once "using" keyword is being used and everything just works. No need to do any kind of import/LOAD_PATH magic.**

just doing that fixed 95% of my problems. I ended up following patterns in accepted answer and also from the comment recommending DrWatson.

Only small thing is the fact that "scripts" don't work well with VSCode. "find all references" or "go to definition" and autocomplete don't work. They do work for everything within "YourPackage.jl" and it's imports perfectly and so does Revise. It's really tiny thing since scripts are usually like 3 lines of code.